# Calling the SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog method

Tags: web-part, javascript, error, user-controls

My SharePoint solution has a userControl that Register a js block

```
string getJS(string title, string htmlContent)
 {
     return (string.Format(@"
          ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {{
                      var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                      options.title = '{0}';
                      options.html = '{1}';
                      options.autoSize = true;
                      options.showClose=true;
                      options.allowMaximize=false;
                      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }}, 'sp.js');"
          , title, "<div>Blah blah</div>"));
  }
```

I have registered the `sp.ui.dialog.js` to make sure that this function is available

```
<Sharepoint:ScriptLink ID="slSAAuto" Name="sp.ui.dialog.js" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" runat="server"></Sharepoint:ScriptLink>
```

I register my JS block at run time

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(Page), "popupOnPageLoad", getJS(title,htmlContent), true);
```

after page loads, i got a JS error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object <div>Blah blah</div> has no method 'getElementsByTagName'
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for starters, I think you have called the `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function in a wrong way.(You have given an extra set of curly braces for the function inside. Try this code:

```
string getJS(string title, string htmlContent)
 {
     return (string.Format(@"
          ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
                      var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
                      options.title = '{0}';
                      options.html = '{1}';
                      options.autoSize = true;
                      options.showClose=true;
                      options.allowMaximize=false;
                      SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
            }, 'sp.js');"
          , title, "<div>Blah blah</div>"));
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Also, `options.html` needs a valid DOM element. You are passing a string containing `<div>Blah Blah</div>` right now.

It should be done like this:

```
var divElem = document.createElement('div');
divElem.innerHTML = 'Blah Blah';

//Rest of your Code.

options.html = divElem;
```

Comment: the extra braces are for escaping.. inside `string.Format` you need to escape the `{` and `}` else you'll get `input is not in a correct format` exception

Comment: but you have already given a `@` at the start of the string. Do you still need to escape the `{` and `}`?

Comment: Check out the edit to my answer.