# Model PopUp in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: modal-dialog, popup

I'm trying to set up a pop up window with a URL to a document each time my Sharepoint site is loaded.

I read that it can be done by adding a content editor web part with a following code to a page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/14/sp.ui.dialog.js">
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "http://www.google.com";
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);</script>
```

But I'm getting nothing. Please help identify what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Try removing 14 from src attribute

Comment: Didn't work. BTW, should sp.ui.dialog.js file be uploaded somewhere to sharepoint or can it be in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS    ?

Comment: It resides in layouts.  Try using sp.sod.executefunc. I  am on mobile and can't give you full details.  Search for sp.sod.executefunc or executeordelayuntilscriptloaded

Comment: Nadeem Yousuf, thanks for a suggestion, I'll try that and report a result.

Comment: Nadeem,I tried using sp.sod.executefunc, got no errors and no warnings, but did't get a popup window I need.

Comment: BTW, doing it with sp.sod.executefunc doesn't give any relust and gives this error in Mozila console: "TypeError: SP.Res is undefined".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short summary of what I did:

1- Added CEWP to my page and set Chrome type to none.

2- Added these refferences to a page itself:

```
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3- Copied *.js files from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033 to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LAYOUTS

A code from CEWP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(popupwin,10000);
function popupwin(){ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function ()
{var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx";
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);},'sp.js');}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you cannot put script tags into a CEWP.

In 2013 there is a Script Editor web part that works, but not in 2010.

The way to get around this issue is to load the script from a document.

Put the script into a .txt file (use notepad or something).

Upload it into one of the libraries on your site. It would be SharedDocuments or StyleLibrary.

Go into the web part settings of the CEWP and past the url of the file you just uploaded into the `Content Link` field.

Here is a [tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/04/14/using-the-javascript-object-model-in-a-content-editor-web-part.aspx?Redirected=true).

Comment: I don't know why people never suggest using the HTML form web part. You can put scripts inside it without having to first create a separate file

Comment: Hmm, interesting, never knew that existed. I guess I don't know enough about it to suggest it to anyone.

Comment: Putting it in a separate file, and putting that file in Site assets and linking CEWP to that file didn't help.

Comment: MdMazzotti, could you please specify how exactly can I do it with a HTML form web part, because I tried and seems like I'm doing something wrong again.

Comment: Are you getting an error on the page? (hit f12 to see javascript errors). Try linking to something that is not google. I got this error `Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/?IsDlg=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.`

Comment: Here is what I'm getting GET http://win-ne5v0om19lh/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 18ms]
13:45:43.085 ReferenceError: IEnumerator is not defined sp.runtime.debug.js:3091
13:45:43.312 GET http://win-ne5v0om19lh/_layouts/ps.debug.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 33ms]
13:45:43.313 GET http://win-ne5v0om19lh/_layouts/sp.init.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 2ms]
13:45:43.187 TypeError: SP.ScriptUtility is undefined sp.debug.js:11

Comment: try [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/33086/calling-the-sp-ui-modaldialog-showmodaldialog-method) you need to use `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` because you are calling the dialog before some required scripts are loaded.

Comment: I modified my code as you adviced: 
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoadedc(function ()
{var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.title = "My Dialog Title";
options.width = 400;
options.height = 600;
options.url = "my URL";
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);},'sp.js');
</script>

Comment: And nothing is happening.
Please advice what's wrong here.

Comment: Guys, 
Please advice.

Comment: You need to use the original code you had combined with the execute...script function, not just copy the example script.

Comment: But that's exactly what I did:
`code`<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/SP.UI.Dialog.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoadedc(function () {var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions(); options.title = "My Dialog Title"; options.width = 400; options.height = 600; options.url = "my URL"; SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);},'sp.js'); </script>

Comment: Are you getting an error still or just nothing?

Comment: ReferenceError: ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoadedc is not defined

Comment: You have `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoadedc` needs to be `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`

Comment: Thanks. Now it's saying: 
TypeError: SP.Res is undefined

Comment: Could you please advice re error above?

Comment: Guys please advice how can TypeError: SP.Res is undefined be handled.

Comment: It seems that that file or function is not defined. I would play around with making sure that the required file exists before calling the function. You may have to throw the code into a `window.setTimeout(func,10000)` and see if it works then (it will wait 10 seconds). If that still gives the error you are missing a required file.

Comment: Thanks thantos, 
Running function with window.setTimeout() helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put this script in Content Editor Webpart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //******** Basic Dialog Starts Here ***********/
 function openBasicDialog(tUrl, tTitle) {
     var options = {
         url: tUrl,
         title: tTitle,
         width: 1500,
        height: 1000
     };
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
 }
 //******** Basic Dialog Ends Here ***********/</script><a href="#" onclick="openBasicDialog('https://abc.com','Welcome Page');">ShowModal Dialog</a>
```

OR

```
<a onclick='javascript:NewItem2(event, "http://www.google.com");javascript:return false;' 

href="https://www.google.com" target="_self">Show google In Modal Window</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that won't work in my case, because I need that window to popup automatically, not after hitting a link.