# Open SP page in a model popup and click close should close browser

Tags: 2010, content-editor-web-part, popup

I want to open a sharepoint page to be opened in a model popup with only close option. I should be able to adjust the size of the popup as well . And onclick of close ,the browser should be closed . I would like to do this using Content Editor WP and want to see the page with master page data and navigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add script in Content Editor WP, to open the page as dialog,

Load first SP.js and add following script

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
     var dialogurl = "your url";
            var options = {
            url: dialogurl,
            width: 700,
            height: 700,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: OnDialogClose
            };
            SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);}, "sp.js");
```

When the user clicks the submit form, you would run the following line of JS:

```
 function OnDialogClose(dialogResult, returnValue)  {
     if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
         // to close
     SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
     } else {
        // logic 
     }
```

other options to set for dialog follow the below link
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: As the user wants to close the Browser window, the window can only be closed if it was opened by JavaScript.. In order to achieve that `window.open('', '_self', ''); window.close();` this should work..

Comment: Cannot see the master page contents of the page in the popup .

Comment: Can you elaborate page type? its a content page or oob list page?

Comment: Similar issue : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94181/model-popup-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: its a content page .